# Is there a way to detect event listeners of a broadcast?

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-scope

When broadcasting from my rootScope, if there are no event listeners listening for my event, I'd like to run my own function in the rootScope. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not near a computer where I can quickly validate, but i think you can use:

```
$rootScope.$$listenerCount[eventName] === 0
```

Comment: I had to check that it wasn't `'undefined'` but this worked. Thanks.